# pass complex data to get call if api

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a viewmodel data to get call in web api..

here is the viewmodel properties

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    public int StateID { get; set; }

    public int DistrictID { get; set; }

    public int UniversityID { get; set; }

    public int CollegeID { get; set; }

    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

here is the ajaxcall that i am trying to ..

> to convert formdata to json object

```
function toSimpleJson() {

    });
    return json;
}
```

> ```
>   the ajax call
> ```

```
function GetFilteredRecords() {

var filterOptions = toSimpleJson();

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/workassign',
    data: JSON.stringify(filterOptions),
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger
    }
});
```

}

here is the filteroptions data

[image]

> here is the api controller get action

```
public IEnumerable<WorkAssignViewModel> Get([FromUri]FilterViewModel date)
    {

    }
```

here i am getting the form data into json object and the passing to controller by using json.stringify() which is suggested and in controller using [FROMUri] but still values are null......

please suggest me a solution to overcome

thank you..

Comment: What is the value of `filterOptions` and what are the properties of `FilterViewModel`? (and note setting the `contentType` option is pointless - its a GET and has no body)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your reply and i added the properties and filteroptions data..

Comment: Just use `data: filterOptions,` (and since you seem to have generated the view correctly (at least based on the little you have shown, you can delete your `toSimpleJson()` function and just use `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that work's fine after removing json.stringify().... thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `JSON.stringify() and`contentType`from the ajax call. You making a GET and a GET does not have a body (therefore`contentType` option is pointless). You code ajax call should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/workassign',
    data: filterOptions,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) {
        debugger
    }
});
```

Note that is you have generated you form controls correctly based on the view having `@model FilterViewModel` and using the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the form controls (`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegionID)` etc), then you can simply use `data: #('form').serialize(),`